# input entry disappearing on first time but stays on 2nd enter

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a competition form at

http://media.serviceportal.com.au/service05/igasummer2013.do

Please go through the form using any browser like Chrome.
Tab through the elements until you reach the "Total purchase amount on receipt*"

On that associated input field type any number, then press tab again.

The value dissapears. Now type again in that field. The value stays.

:( Why is the value disappearing on first input entry?

Please help. I appreciate your help very much

I have the following javascript to make the price 2 digits

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(function() {
            $('#custom2').blur(function() {
                var amt = parseFloat(this.value);
                $(this).val(amt.toFixed(2));
            });
        });
</script>
```

And validating using jquery validation

```
....

    rules: {
      custom2: {
        required: true,
        number: true,
      },

....
```

Comment: The value stays on first number entering

Comment: Actually try again now. I was debugging it and did something to find out what may be causing the issue.. I think the issue is caused by that javascript code. If I take it out, the value stays. But if I have it, then the value dissapears on first try. Now try again please

Comment: The value still exists. I am typing 23 and press tab, it becomes 23.00 on first try

Comment: Yeah weird. All I did was to restart the server and push all the latest files back to the prod.. Hmm oh well... Either me or clients or somewhere down the lines someone was seeing ghostly stuffs. Thank you for all your help mate. It does seem to be working now. Nothing wrong in any part of my code I see. Cheers. Take care